# No module named 'psutil'

Tags: python, kivy

I already installed :
I restarted terminal also.

```
(env-kivy)
pip3 install psutil
```

OS : windows
kivy 2.0
python3

```
   import psutil

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
```

Comment: try use `python -m pip install psutil` instead `pip3 install psutil`

Comment: Already done : `$ python -m pip install psutil
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in g:\web_\\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages (5.8.0)
(kivy_venv) `

Comment: How do you run your kivy script?

Comment: First ` kivy_venv\Scripts\activate`  then python3 main.py

Comment: use `python main.py`. maybe python3 will point to another python

Comment: Thk for collaboration Mr. @eyllanesc . Works fine with `python main.py`!

Comment: So the error is that you have another python named "python3" that caused the error.

Comment: I forced from begin python3 , i little new in py area. Till now app works fine with lot of dep imports ... Now i see why i needed `kivy_venv/Scripts/python.exe` to make package proccess work...